# How to store Access token value in javascript cookie and pass that token to Header using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form, as shown below:

```
<form method="post" name="logForm" onsubmit="onLogin()" action="dashbooard.html">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" >
</form>
```

Now when I click on the Login button, I am authenticated by the server and an `access_token` is generated and returned back to me via a REST API.

I would like to store that `access_token` in a cookie and pass that token into a request. But, I don't know how to do this. I would love to receive help on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Are you wanting to set the cookie with straight JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: By using javascript, and after storing access_token i have to pass that access_token value through header. and i have to delete the cookie when user get Logout.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you can use a cookie for your question regarding the `access_token`:

**1. Storing the cookie on the client:**

`document.cookie='access_token=[value]'` where `[value]` is the token value.

If we use a reader/writer library that MDN provides [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), we can do the above as:

`docCookies.setItem('access_token', [value]);`

The reason why we would use something like this instead of the standard way is to make it easier to access and delete the token, as demonstrated in #3 below.

**2. Passing the cookie back to the server:**

We need to send the `access_token` back to the server through the header.

This should automatically be done for you, assuming that the server sends a response after authentication like `Set-Cookie: access_token=[value]`.

If for any reason you encounter an issue regarding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, here is an example of how you can set `Access-Control` response headers for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

**3. Deleting the cookie:**

Using the reader/writer library linked in #1, we can do the following:

`docCookies.removeItem('acccess_token');`

**Security considerations when using cookies for authorization:**

XSS, MITM, and CSRF attack vectors should be considered when using cookies for authorization. On a basic level:

- For [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks, we can set the `HttpOnly` flag in the response header by the server to prevent a client side script from accessing the cookie.
- For [MITM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks, we can use the `Secure` flag to guarantee the cookie is not sent over an unencrypted HTTP channel.
- For [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) attacks, the recommendation by OWASP is the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern). It's basically a randomly generated token that is sent by the server and is sent back by the client to verify a request submission done by the user.

Comment: I believe we can now use the `sameSite` flag to prevent CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

Comment: why this error gives:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://murmuring-fjord-2343.herokuapp.com/delete. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. and how to solve this issue.?

Comment: You are using this by ajax ? if yes then make sure that type must be "jsonp"

Comment: sorry! when i write at the place of json to jsonp, the entire code is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in your login route handler:

```js
const option = {
  expiresIn: "24h"
}
res.cookie("token", yourtoken, option)
```

This will save the the token in your cookie

You can also do this:

```js
const yourToken = whatever your token is 
localStorage.serItem("key" , yourtoken)
```

You can access `yourtoken` with your key when ever you want

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please fix the formatting.

Answer (score -1):

A more elaborated answer based on above answers, in the success part of your Ajax call.

```
 success: function (json) {
                // console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
                var access_token = json.token;
                document.cookie="access_token="+access_token;
            },
```